# How to run C#/.NET code (VSTO) directly from Microsoft Excel (VSTO)

Tags: c#, .net, excel, vsto, ms-office

I would like to call some webservices from Microsoft Excel.
I have no experience with this, but I've created an "Excel VSTO Workbook" project in Visual Studio 2019 and my Worksheet1_Change event fires as expected - if I run the project from Visual Studio (F5).

When I open the .xlsx file (from the project folder or the bin\Debug folder), my code is not run. Excel does not even ask me if I would like to turn on macros or anything.

How can I run the code from Excel without Visual Studio?

Comment: You need to do some reading the in the VSTO documentation. The VSTO workbook needs to *installed*. But if you don't want the code to be associate with that workbook, only, look at making an *Add-in*. With a VSTO project Excel will *not* show any macro security prompts. VSTO code is *not* VBA "macros".

Comment: "When I open the .xlsx file .... Excel does not even ask me if I would like to turn on macros or anything" - an xlsx file doesn't contain macros - you would need an .xlsm file for that.  Why are you calling these webservices "directly" though - shouldn't you be calling the webservice itself ?

Comment: @CindyMeister Thanks, "installing" was a good keyword. I'll probably write an add-in in the end, but the reason I started out with a workbook project was that I want to was hoping that would make it easier to demo a prototype (just email the .xlsx file + .dll). Is that not possible? It seems like the .xlsx file just stores a reference to the DLL in a property. But then why doesn't my code run when I open the .xlsx file from the bin\Debug folder? Do I really have to build an .msi package or so, for a single workbook?

Comment: Also, sorry for the poor wording. I know that C# is not VBA (macros). What I meant was that Excel doesn't even prompt me if I want to run custom code when I open the .xlsx file from bin\Debug. But when I hit F5 in Visual Studio, everything works just fine.

Comment: "*the reason I started out with a workbook project was that I want to was hoping that would make it easier to demo a prototype (just email the .xlsx file + .dll). Is that not possible?*" No, that only works with VBA, not any other method of programming Office. A VSTO solution needs to be installed. And because the user *must* decide to install, there is no warning or prompt or anything when a VSTO document-level customization is opened. You really, really, really need to take a couple of hours to read the documentation (design, etc., not the "APIs")

Comment: @CindyMeister Thank you. After some more googling, I stumbled across the new Office Add-Ins that are based on JavaScript. Seems like that may be a better fit for me anyway.

Comment: Excel certainly has a good start on a complete JS object model (unlike Word or, worse, PowerPoint). Note that the e-mail distribution idea still won't be possible, but once the add-in is on SharePoint or in the Office Store (or whatever) installation is much simpler for the user.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install all the required prerequisites before running your document-level add-in within a document on the end-user machine. To get the job done developers create an installer for the solution. There are two main ways of deploying Office solutions:

1. [Deploy an Office solution by using ClickOnce](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/deploying-an-office-solution-by-using-clickonce?view=vs-2019)
2. [Deploy an Office solution by using Windows Installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/deploying-an-office-solution-by-using-windows-installer?view=vs-2019)

The other side of the coin is that any Office solution can be disabled automatically if any unhandled exception takes its place in the code.

Microsoft Office applications can disable VSTO Add-ins that behave unexpectedly. If an application does not load your VSTO Add-in, the application might have hard disabled or soft disabled your VSTO Add-in.

Hard disabling can occur when a VSTO Add-in causes the application to close unexpectedly. It might also occur on your development computer if you stop the debugger while the Startup event handler in your VSTO Add-in is executing.

Soft disabling can occur when a VSTO Add-in produces an error that does not cause the application to unexpectedly close. For example, an application might soft disable a VSTO Add-in if it throws an unhandled exception while the Startup event handler is executing.

When you re-enable a soft-disabled VSTO Add-in, the application immediately attempts to load the VSTO Add-in. If the problem that initially caused the application to soft disable the VSTO Add-in has not been fixed, the application will soft disable the VSTO Add-in again. Read more about that in the [How to: Re-enable a VSTO Add-in that has been disabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-re-enable-a-vsto-add-in-that-has-been-disabled?view=vs-2019) article.